# Resetting object's coordinates

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am developing a Flash game in which I have planes flying across the screen. I have created six instances of the same movie clip. Each has different coordinates, however I expect it to behave in the same way with the `hitTest`. However, the planes coordinates do not reset after they fly across the screen once.

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame) 
{
    this._x -= 30;

    if(this.hitTest(_root.PlayerPlane))
    {
        gotoAndPlay("Game Over", 1);
        stop();
    }

    if (this._x == 30)
    {
        this.x = 1459.0;
        play();
    }
}
```

Once `X == 30` I want the object to reset to original position, and play, but nothing happens.

Each of the layers within the project is 1 frame long, apart from the background. I made a Classic Tween inside that for the background to move between Frame 1 and 50.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is never 30 but smaller than 30, nothing will happen.

```
if (this._x <= 30)
            ^
```

This should fix it.
And why do you sometimes use `x` with underscore and sometimes without?